# Communicating with SQL Server DB Online through Webservice and Restful API

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, rest, asp.net-web-api, model-view-controller

I have a project set up in ASP.Net MVC using a SQL Server database.

My team and I need to develop the mobile aspect which is used to capture the Clocking In and Clocking Out times of employees through scanning QR Codes.

We are thinking of using IONIC3 to build the Mobile App.

If anyone could please assist me in guiding me as to what steps to take to ensure communication and capturing of clocking in and out times of the employees on the online database.

1. Is Azure a good option for the hosting of the DB ?
2. How should I go about making the Restful API (Any links that will help with my situation will be greatly appreciated.)
3. How should I go about doing the Web Service?

I am struggling the most with understanding how and what to do when it comes to communicating to the Online SQL Server database to ensure that the clocking in and clocking out times of specific employees will be captured to the database online.

Sorry, I am new to RESTful services and working with online databases.

Any help will be greatly appreciated, thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is very simple thing :

1. Azure or AWS both are good for hosting DB.
2. You just need to create simple webapi project.
3. Online communication to DB is nothing you just need to ensure that DB should be accessible from your environments (DEV/QA/UAT/PRODUCTION).